# How to convert to QString from const char* result from ffmpeg C function

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, encoding, char

I use the ffmpeg library in c++ / qt project

```
extern "C" {
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/dict.h>
}
```

With this I read the media metadata from a local music file. This works quite fine:

```
avformat_open_input(&format_song, path, NULL, NULL);

while((tag = av_dict_get(format_song->metadata, "", tag, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX))){
                std::cout << tag.key << tag.value << std::endl;
                // tag.value is a const char* (but in C!?)
}
```

Altough the encoding of the `tag.value` seems to be different for files (maybe saved different in the id3tags). Here are some examples of different title values for different files:

```
"TÃ¶hne" [ö]
"Die Ã„rzte" [Ä]
"Für Immer"
```

**How to convert this to a readable QString?**

There are some problems with the encoding of special characters. For most cases the following works:

```
QString result = QString(tag->value).normalized(QString::NormalizationForm_C);
//or:
QString result = QString::fromUtf8(tag->value);
```

But sometimes this results in a U+FFFD � REPLACEMENT CHARACTER for some "Ü" "Ä" "ß" etc. chars.
But in in that cases `fromLocal8Bit` works. So I end up testing for replacement characters and choose a different conversion:

```
if(result.contains(QChar::ReplacementCharacter)){
      result = QString::fromLocal8Bit(tag->value);
}
```

**I expect there is a better way to do this?**

Comment: Do you know the encoding of the strings? Is there a way to get the encoding? Then you can use that for creating the `QString` objects. If there's no way to get the actual encoding, then you have to live with your strings sometimes being wrong.

Comment: No. Altough the API says it assumes to be utf8 http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__metadata__api.html

Comment: `QString::fromUtf8()`

Comment: You need to know, up front, what encoding the source string is using. QString can't just guess it. If you don't know you'll have to either guess or do some in-depth analysis on the source string to determine it (that could get complicated).